# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/products from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, proxy

```
import express from 'express';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import { generateToken } from '../utils.js';

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post(
  '/cart/signin',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
        res.send({
          _id: user._id,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
          token: generateToken(user),
        });
        return;
      }
    }
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid email or password' });
  })
);

export default userRouter;
```

this is happening in the advanced rest client to test the data is reaching the server

x-powered-by:
Express
content-type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length:
39
etag:
W/"27-Mm37A2ls1bgL0/D8e3MSpDLbow8"
connection:
keep-alive
keep-alive:
timeout=5

{
"message": "Invalid email or password"
}

Comment: I see in the error message that it says `Cannot POST /api/users/signin` but your route is `'/cart/signin'`

Comment: What I mean is that the route you're posting to needs to include `/cart/signin` because that's the URL you have assigned it

Comment: yeahh.. after i changed the route to '/signin' it is saying that 

{
"message": "Invalid email or password"
}

Comment: and also cross checked once again if there is a typo in the code..

Comment: So it's all working now?

Comment: Not working....

Comment: it has to give the data

Comment: import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const Data = {
  users: [
    {
      name: 'Laxman',
      email: 'admin@example.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('123456'),
      isAdmin: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Manvit',
      email: 'user@example.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('123456'),
      isAdmin: false,
    },
  ],




here is the Data I have fetching

Comment: I entered data is correct but it's showing invalid email or password

Comment: You need to post both the client side api call as well as the backend code so that we can see what's happening. If you're getting  `invalid email or password` it's most likely that your value is not being received in the backend so do a `console.log(req.body.email)` to check that it's coming through

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).